# Way does not passing an argument to an anonymous function cause it to return a function

Tags: javascript, oop, anonymous-function

Why does passing passing an argument to an anonymous function effect the results?  For instance, the below script shows a1 as a `function()`, and a2 as an array.

```
var a1=(function(){return [1*2,2*2,3*2];});
var a2=(function(v){return [1*v,2*v,3*v];})(2);
console.log(a1,a2);
```

results:

```
function() [2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line of code never calls the function.

Writing `var a = function() { ... }` will assign the function itself to `a`.

Your second line does call the function, just like any other function call, using `(2)`.

Comment: Really?  Why not?  Why does the second line actually call the function?

Comment: @user1032531: Why do you think it does call the function?

Comment: Wow, I think I always misunderstood.  The first line defines the function, the second calls it. Therefore (untested), `a1(2)` should return something.

Comment: @user1032531: Yes; `a1(2)` does return something.  However, that does not affect `a1`.

Comment: Off topic and I will select your answer in 4 minutes, but does the anonymous function have access to all variables available to it's immediate parent?  My testing seems to say it does.

Comment: @user1032531: Yes; that's called a closure.  It's one of the beauties of Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

because all the assignment to a1 does is create an anonymous function but doesn't actually execute it.

the assignment to a2 creates *and* executes the function at the same time because you've added the parens afterwards to actually invoke it.

to create equivalent code, you'd need something like this:

```
var a1=(function(){return [1*2,2*2,3*2];})(); <-- note the extra parens
var a2=(function(v){return [1*v,2*v,3*v];})(2);
console.log(a1,a2);
```

Comment: Thanks Mike.  This was a concept that I was unaware of.